# how to make a gmail addon which works without opening the email message like task and calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, add-on, gmail-addons

I want to make a Gmail add-on which can work without opening message like other add-ons - calendar, task, copper, etc.

I tried universalActions and contextualTriggers functions in the manifest file

`contextualTriggers": [{
      "unconditional": {
      },
      "onTriggerFunction": "buildAddOn"
    }],`

error: Select an email for  to recommend content for you

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/accessing-addons) , Gmail add-ons that you have installed automatically appear in the Gmail user interface when you open or compose a message. 
The only triggers that are available for Gmail addon are **contextualTriggers** that is triggered when a message is opened and **composeTrigger** that is opened from Gmail compose interface. You can refer to [this](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/triggers).